# Datetime issue in odoo10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

in my custom model I defined the fields

```
time_from = fields.Datetime(string="Time From", default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

time_to = fields.Datetime(string="Time To", default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

tot_time = fields.Char("Time Difference", compute='_get_time')
```

this is my compute function

```
@api.depends('time_from', 'time_to')
def _get_time(self):
    t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.time_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.time_to, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if t2<t1:
        raise ValidationError('Time To must greater than Time From')
    time_diff = (t2-t1)
    self.tot_time = time_diff
```

This is success fully prints time difference. 
Time from and time to are **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.**

How to change this to **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss** format

I changed the format like this **'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'** .
but it is not getting correct result.

How to change the format?

is it possible to calculate time difference in this format?

Comment: You should notice that the defaults you're defining don't change.  Those fields will default to the last time your .py module was loaded into the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` and `Datetime` are saved as strings in the database in a certain format (see the class definition on `fields.py`. You cannot change the format that is used for the fields in the ORM. If you want to change the format of the date or datetime when you show these fields you can do it not from the code but from:

1) Settings -> Translations -> Find your language and inside you can change the way the fields Date and Datetime are rendered on the client side.

2) If you have a template/report you can use for example`<p t-esc="formatLang(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" />` or another expression you want to change how the date or datetime will be formed.

3) In the field definition in your xml files you can use custom javascript/widget that will do the rendering.

Comment: George Daramouskas:thanks for the information  about date and datetime